# Declare variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I get an error message:

> Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
>   Each `GROUP BY` expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

from this T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @CLIENT_COUNT INT

SELECT @CLIENT_COUNT = COUNT(CLT_NBR) FROM CLIENT

SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN STATUS = 3 
          THEN 'CATEGORY1' 
          ELSE 'CATEGORY2' 
    END AS Category,
    COUNT(*) AS COUNT,
    @CLIENT_COUNT as [Total CLIENT],
    COUNT(*) / @CLIENT_COUNT as PERCENTAGE
FROM 
    CLIENT_STATUS
WHERE 
    STATUS IN (3, 8)
GROUP BY 
    STATUS, @CLIENT_COUNT
```

Can you help me to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. You need to put all of the values that need to be returned before `FROM`.

```
DECLARE @CLIENT_COUNT INT

SELECT @CLIENT_COUNT = COUNT(CLT_NBR)
FROM CLIENT

SELECT CASE 
    WHEN STATUS = 3
        THEN 'CATEGORY1'
    ELSE 'CATEGORY2'
    END AS Category
     , COUNT(STATUS) AS StatusCount
     , @CLIENT_COUNT AS [Total CLIENT]
     , COUNT(STATUS) / @CLIENT_COUNT AS PERCENTAGE
FROM CLIENT_STATUS
WHERE STATUS IN (
       3
      ,8
    )
GROUP BY STATUS
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei! I just changed my question, can you please help me?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I still got the same error after I add @CLIENT_COUNT IN GROUP BY

Comment: Change the name of the second returned column, Count is a reserved word,  Try StatusCount