# `GROUP BY` expression

Tags: sql, t-sql

I got an error message:

> Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 18

Each `GROUP BY` expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference from the below TSQL:

```
DECLARE @CLIENT_COUNT INT

SELECT @CLIENT_COUNT=COUNT(CLT_NBR) FROM CLIENT

SELECT 
CASE WHEN STATUS=3 THEN 'CATEGORY1' else 'CATEGORY2' end as Category

,COUNT(*) AS COUNT 

,@CLIENT_COUNT as [Total CLIENT]

,COUNT(*) / @CLIENT_COUNT as PERCENTAGE

FROM CLIENT_STATUS

WHERE STATUS IN (3,8)

GROUP BY STATUS,@CLIENT_COUNT
```

Can you help me to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Try removing `@CLIENT_COUNT` from your `GROUP BY`, since it's a constant anyway.

Comment: Duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727631/declare-variable, also change the name of the alias of the second column, it's a reserved word.